# Django, nginx and uWSGI : uWSGI workers keep dying and reloading

Tags: python, django, mongodb, nginx, uwsgi

We are using mongodb in our application.
Our python process (django app) reads data from mongodb and based on some calculations it sends an HttpResponse.
Now the problem is, the data read from mongodb is quite large.
Every query size is nearly 900MB (1 Gb in some cases).
Our python process goes out of memory and throws an **MemoryError**, due to which uWSGI worker process dies and spawns again.

My uwsgi.conf :

```
        [uwsgi]
chdir=/var/www/MERU/Meru/deviceapp/meru_device/
pythonpath=/var/www/MERU/Meru/deviceapp/meru_device/
env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=meru_device.settings
module=meru_device.wsgi:application
uid=www-data
gid=www-data
socket=/tmp/da.sock
daemonize=/tmp/da.log
processes=2
master=true
listen=512
harakiri=80
memory-report=true
limit-as=1024
reload-on-as=1024
reload-on-rss=512
pidfile=/tmp/da.pid
chmod-socket=666
vacuum=true
max-requests=5000
```

My uwsgi_params file :

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

My nginx.conf :

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/da.sock;
}

server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name <my-elastic-ip>;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /meru-nms {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /var/www/MERU/Meru/deviceapp/meru_device/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    }
}
```

Do we need to increase memory limit for the python process ?
Or do we need to increase address space limit for uwsgi ?
Can someone point us in the right direction ?

Comment: I'd recommend finding a solution that doesn't involve 1GB query sizes instead of trying to deal with the symptoms of a 1GB query.

Comment: agree with Scott, you already found the problem by yourself (you voluntary limited the address space of your processes), having requests with such an impact is a bad idea

Comment: @roberto : I still face the same problem, If I remove the address space limitation on uWSGI process.

Comment: What, if I further increase the address space limit on uWSGI process ??

Comment: you have even reload-on-as=1024
reload-on-rss=512, but if you still get python MemoryError (after having removed the three options), you may have completely exhausted resources or you could have some other enforcement not governed by uWSGI.

Comment: @roberto : Thanks for the reply.I have not limited any process to a specific address space usage.If I increased reload-on-as and reload-on-rss, still I got the MemoryError.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to setup memory profiling for your application - you can write simple middleware that runs your views with profiler. As profiler you can use [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).